# Angular 6 ngFor values is updating when changing the input value

Tags: angular, angular6

I am not familiar with Angular 2, 3, 4 & 5 and I am trying to get a better understanding of Angular 6.

**Problem**: I am pushing an user object to the users array then when I change the value of inputs, all the object inside the array is also changing.

component.ts

```
public data; //user input id,age,first_name,last_name
public users: User[] = [];

constructor() {
    this.data = {};
}

ngOnInit() {
}

btnClick = function () {
    //push the user input to array
    this.users.push(this.data);
};
```

Please check my sample code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ztg1k

Comment: How are you changing the user input? Can you please post the full code including the template?

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick you can check my sample code here. Thank you for your help. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1ztg1k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are bound to the same `data` reference after pushing the `data` object in the array. After adding the item in the array, the text input is still referring to the earlier `data` reference through `[(ngModel)]="data.first_name"` which is in the array.

All you have to do is re-initialize the `data` instance to an empty object literal.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  users = new Array();
  data = {}

  btnClick = function (){
    this.users.push(this.data);
    this.data = {};
  }
}
```

I forked your code and modified it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klrrjd

Comment: Thank you very much @Amardeep Bhowmick. You saved my day. :)

Comment: np :) @MarkRobinGaspar